# LDAP error during committing changes

Tags: vb.net, ldap

I'm currently writing a little app to update AD fields without using Windows tools
It works great unless you press press "Update"

LDAP commit returns an error and I don't know which one

```
If (sn.Text <> "" And givenname.Text <> "" And employeeId.Text <> "") Then
        If Int32.TryParse(employeeId.Text, id) Then
            Dim infos As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ad.mairie-blagnac.fr/<GUID=" + user_guid + ">")

            infos.Properties("sn").Value = sn.Text
            infos.Properties("givenname").Value = givenname.Text
            infos.Properties("displayName").Value = sn.Text + " " + givenname.Text
            infos.Properties("employeeId").Value = employeeId.Text
            infos.Properties("physicaldeliveryofficename").Value = physicaldeliveryofficename.Text
            infos.Properties("company").Value = company.Text
            infos.Properties("department").Value = department.Text
            infos.Properties("title").Value = title.Text
            infos.Properties("employeeNumber").Value = employeeNumber.SelectedValue
            infos.Properties("employeeType").Value = employeeType.SelectedValue
            infos.Properties("streetAddress").Value = streetAddress.Text
            infos.Properties("homephone").Value = homephone.Text
            infos.Properties("telephoneNumber").Value = telephoneNumber.Text
            infos.Properties("pager").Value = pager.Text

            infos.CommitChanges()

        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong employee ID")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Name, last name and employee ID are required")
    End If
```

Not all fields are set (empty)
I have rights to update AD users since I'm domain admin.

Do you guyz have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Found.

I had 3 required fields

```
infos.Properties("sn").Value = sn.Text
infos.Properties("givenname").Value = givenname.Text
infos.Properties("employeeId").Value = employeeId.Text
```

The others fields were empty, and LDAP did not accept that

Final code

```
If (sn.Text <> "" And givenname.Text <> "" And employeeId.Text <> "") Then
        If Int32.TryParse(employeeId.Text, id) Then
            Dim infos As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ad.mairie-blagnac.fr/<GUID=" + user_guid + ">")

            infos.Properties("sn").Value = sn.Text
            infos.Properties("givenname").Value = givenname.Text
            infos.Properties("displayName").Value = sn.Text + " " + givenname.Text
            infos.Properties("employeeId").Value = employeeId.Text

            If physicaldeliveryofficename.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("physicaldeliveryofficename").Value = physicaldeliveryofficename.Text
            End If
            If company.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("company").Value = company.Text
            End If
            If department.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("department").Value = department.Text
            End If
            If title.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("title").Value = title.Text
            End If
            If employeeNumber.SelectedValue <> "" Then
                infos.Properties("employeeNumber").Value = employeeNumber.SelectedValue
            End If
            If employeeType.SelectedValue <> "" Then
                infos.Properties("employeeType").Value = employeeType.SelectedValue
            End If
            If streetAddress.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("streetAddress").Value = streetAddress.Text
            End If
            If homephone.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("homephone").Value = homephone.Text
            End If
            If telephoneNumber.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("telephoneNumber").Value = telephoneNumber.Text
            End If
            If pager.TextLength > 0 Then
                infos.Properties("pager").Value = pager.Text
            End If

            infos.CommitChanges()

            confirm.Text = "User updated"
            For Each item As ListViewItem In list_users.Items
                If item.SubItems(0).Text = varDN Then
                    item.SubItems(0).Text = sn.Text + " " + givenname.Text
                    item.SubItems(1).Text = employeeId.Text
                    item.SubItems(2).Text = title.Text
                    item.SubItems(3).Text = department.Text
                End If
            Next
        Else
        MsgBox("Wrong employee ID")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Name, last name and employee ID are required")
End If
```

If you have any optimization I will take it

Thanks